# What does this media query do exactly

Tags: css, media-queries

Can someone explain how this media query works?

```
/* Tablet Portrait (768px) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The query works exactly as it says it does: It is for media that is a screen device having a minimum width of 321px and maximum width of 1024px and a portrait orientation. What part of that is giving you trouble?

Comment: basics of Media Queries - [LINK HERE](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/an-introduction-to-css3-media-queries.html#fbid=nLOEGmysuKa)

Comment: Whether it affected sizes between those 2 numbers or the 2 separate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rules apply only to screen devices with a minimum width of 321px, a maximum width of 1024px and a screen orientation of portrait.

In practice, this would be a tablet sized screen (bigger than 320px wide) when it is in portrait.

Comment: So it will affect everything from 321px up to to 1024px?

Comment: Yes, if it is a screen device in portrait mode.

Comment: Could i ditch this one and make it into 2 different queries? Im wanting a div to be a certain size on 321px and at 1024px

Comment: Absolutely. You could use this one for generalised tablet rules, and two more for something a little more specific

Comment: Wouldnt having this one plus another for 321 and another for 1024 conflict?

Comment: Im trying to get a div containing a background image to be a certain height on different screens so the pages content can be seen close to the top of the page on all device widths.

Comment: Overlapping media queries can work, but it's probably simpler to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Rules apply only on screens (not on printers etc.) when with of deivce: 321px < device-width < 1024 and portrait orientation.